# Guys, who knows how you can implement the link format for phone calls in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Guys, who knows how you can implement the link format for phone calls in React (href = ”tel: ...”), Can I use “Link” from “react-router-dom”?
Not in React Native!

Comment: React will ultimately end up generating regular HTML. Just make the equivalent in JSX and it should work the same.

Comment: It's just `<a href="tel:+123456789">`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pretty standard way

```
<a href="tel:PHONE_NUM"> PHONE_NUM </a>
```

Answer (score 7):

You'll want to set it to a dynamic property, that includes a the string at the beginning of it

```
<a href={"mailto:" + this.props.email}>email</a>
```

Comment: Just with the `tel:` scheme for telephone numbers!

Answer (score 3):

You can use this way

Without Varibale

```
<a href="tel:number" >number</a>
```

With Variable

```
<a href={"tel:" + mobile}>{mobile}</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

To implement it in the React way, you need to follow these steps:

1. Import the "Link" from "react-router-dom" module.
2. Use the imported "Link" component in your React code.
3. Set the "to" prop of the "Link"component to the desired link or URL.

Here's an example :

```js
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

// ...

<Link to="tel:9876543210">9876543210</Link>
```

When rendered in the DOM, it will appear as a clickable link to the phone number "9876543210".